# Hide 'option' element in iphone

Tags: css, iphone

Here is the html:

```
<select>
   <option style="display:none;">1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Here is the result on Chrome - Desktop

[image: Chrome Desktop]

And here is the result in iPhone - Safari

[image: iPhone Safari]

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jusiboho/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could disable or remove it using jQuery

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/1728/

```
<select>
   <option class="targetThis">1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
function isiPhone(){
    return (
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) ||
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1)
    );
}
if(isiPhone()){
   $(".targetThis").attr('disabled', true);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to remove it. I want that the default value of the combobox will be "1", but it can't be selected.

Comment: Is not there a way to do it that way will work as in desktop - be completely hidden?

Comment: You can not `hide` the option, only remove it. CSS browser support for options is very very limited. The alternative would be to create a list using `<ul>` and making it look like a select menu.